# findAllWhere and List fetch

Tags: grails, grails-orm

So I have the domain class as follows:

```
class Enrollment {
    Course course
    Date date
    User user
    static constraints = {

    }
}
```

In my controller, I have this action :

```
def persons =  Enrollment.list(fetch :[user : "a"])
        render persons
```

I am trying to fetch only a user named "a" and its corresponding map. But it displays all..I tried `FindAllWhere` but throws an error

```
No such property: user for class: tester.EnrollmentController
```

Comment: I tried get and read to fetch individual users but i cannot compare it..

Comment: The `Enrollment.list(..)` part is totally wrong: the `list` method on a domain class takes pagination and sorting parameters, not filters. Valid parameters would be for instance `Enrollment.list(max: 20, offset: 2, sort: 'date', order: 'desc')`

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the `User` class has a `name` property.

What about:

```
def user = User.findByName("a")
def persons = user ? Enrollment.findAllByUser(user) : []
```

Assuming here that you can find a unique user (name probably isn't unique enough), otherwise I would do something like:

```
def persons = Enrollment.createCriteria().list{
    user {
       eq('name', "a")
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. Everytime I use find, it throws me an error. FindWhere would totally solve it but I dont know why i am getting these errors

Comment: Can you at least do `Enrollment.list()` and `User.list()`?

Comment: When I tried:    def persons = Enrollment.createCriteria().list{
    user {
       eq('name', "a")
    }
}

Comment: It gives me an error at def persons = Enrollment.createCriteria().list{}

Comment: No signature of method: tester.User.call() is applicable for argument types: (tester.EnrollmentController$_closure1_closure2_closure3)

Comment: Do you have a `user` variable defined somewhere above the criteria block? It seems Groovy wants to run the `{eq('name', 'a')}` on that variable. Try renaming it or using `delegate.user { ... }` in the closure.

Comment: As Gregor said, you must have a `user` defined somewhere that conflicts with the `user` member of the Enrollment class. Also ,are you sure that the `User` type used in Enrollment is the one you expect it to be?

Comment: I gave up on this..I used gsp to code and it works. I will back some other day to figure it out.